# PowerShell (Get-ChildItem).Length bug

Tags: powershell, directory, children

I'm learning to use Windows PowerShell and I noticed that `(Get-ChildItem).Length` returns file size when there is only one file in the directory. Do I have to write my own function to get the length or is there a simpler method?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem |ForEach-Object Length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a bug. When there is more than one file, the command will return an array. With the property Length you will get in this case the size of the array.
Some example how to get the size:

```
Get-ChildItem | select -ExpandProperty Length
```

or

If you want to manipulate the values further, try maybe something like that

```
Get-ChildItem | foreach {$_.Length}
```